# Expressing an NSNumber as a fraction in a UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am working on a matrix calculator which will put an mxn matrix into row echelon form. To present the matrix to the user I have set up an mxn grid of UITextFields. Everything works fine but the only issue is that i would like to be able to display some of the elements, which are NSNumbers, as fractions instead of decimals. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I would say look into CoreText framework from apple

Comment: are you able to use textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",numerator,denominator];

Answer (score 0):

a fraction is a integer number with a fraction part, so just get the integer part of NSNumber, and calc the fraction part. fe:
2.45 
let it be 2 and 0.45 , make 0.45 to 45 by 100, then simplify to 9 by 20